# Java printf cheat: Is this legal?

Tags: java, printf

This cheat compiles and runs just fine in NetBeans. However, it seems like it's probably not legal, for a couple of different reasons. Or is it? It could make code a bit more compact in some situations. Just curious.

```
System.out.printf("%-20d John Smith %n", 12);
```

...which gives me:

```
12                   John Smith
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be legal?

Comment: @David Hoelzer - I'm a newbie (as you can tell), but my thoughts were that it would only work for static strings, and furthermore, that it seemed to possibly mix %d with %s. But reading all the comments, I'm pleased to see that this isn't the case. :)

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I'm sure you won't be arrested for using that line of code.

Comment: @Isambe What *"possibly mix %d with %s"*? You don't have a `%s` in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly legal, `-20` left aligns twenty spaces and `%n` is a newline.

Comment: Yes, but "John Smith" is a string, which would normally be defined to the right of the formatting commands, correct?

Comment: @Isambe consider `System.out.printf("%-20d %s %n", 12, "John Smith");`

Comment: @Isambe If "John Smith" is a fixed string, it's fine to put it into the formatting commands, just like the old school `System.out.printf("Hello, world!");`.

Comment: @Scary Wombat - Yes, that's the normal way to do it, but it adds an extra comma, space and quotation marks. That's why I wondered if the cheat was legal.

Comment: @Nier - Thanks! Cool! :)